# Forcing Re-Initialization of 2 machines in a stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a large stack which has about 10 machines. Of those, 2 are being used for development and so are constantly being changed.

What I would like to be able to do is terminate those 2 instances and then have them recreated. 
Is there a way to easily rebuild only those 2 instances without having to take down and rebuild the whole stack?

Comment: It's a good idea to split off dev machines from your production cloudformation stack, given the possibility of breaking prod (you're probably much more careful then I am though). One could also say that having a completely identical stack for the dev machines would be reason enough to split them.

Answer (score 0):

Typically using an AutoScale group will do that work for you.  I've typically used CloudFormation to create a "dev" stack which would include an ASG and other EC2 bits to make this work easier.